# How to upload image files from multiple devices(raspberrypies) into one Dropbox account?

Tags: python, upload, dropbox

I have two camera modules connected(wired and configured) to two raspberrypies(one for each). These cameras take pictures and save the image onto the pies. 
I have one Dropbox account. I have a code to upload image files (saved in the specified folder) from the pi to my Dropbox account.

So, when I give a command, these two pies start uploading the image files to my Dropbox account at the same time.

And the problem comes into play. 
Always one pi succeed in uploading. The other fails. 
I need help on this. And I am planning to have 20 cameras.
So 20 pies should be able to upload images to one single Dropbox account at the same time.

Thank you for your help. 
I hope the solution is easy and straightforward.

**Code**:

```
import dropbox, sys, os
import os.path
from dropbox.files import WriteMode

dbx=dropbox.Dropbox('my authentication key')
image_dir="/home/pi/somefolder"

for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
     for file in files:
          file_path=os.path.join(dir, file)
          dest_path=os.path.join('/somefolder', file)
          with open(file_path) as f:
               dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dest_path, mute=True, 
               mode=WriteMode('add'))
```

When I run only one pi, the uploading works perfect. No problem at all.
When I run two pies uploading at the same time, always one of them malfunctions.

here I have attached what I get from the malfunctioning pi.

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "scanner.py", line 288, in  dest_path, mute=True, mode=WriteMode('add'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 2293, in files_upload
        f,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 274, in                                                    request
        timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 365, in                                                    request_json_string_with_retry
        timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 449, in                                                    request_json_string
        timeout=timeout,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581,                                                    in post
        return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533,                                                    in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646,                                                    in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516,                                                    in send
        raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='content.dropboxapi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2/files/upload (Caused by New ConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name r  esolution',))

I hope someone can help me with ease. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you please format the trace lines.

Comment: For whatever reason, your raspberry seems to lose the ability to resolve the dropbox address. Try hardcoding a nameserver in it's /etc/resolv.conf. : [Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=157047).

Comment: I think I formatted it better than before.